# Joint different Bundles Virtual Path into single one

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle, virtual-path

I have several Bundles Virtual Paths defined on the `BundleConfig.config` where each one have associated several javascript path files.

What I want is to join all this virtual paths in a single one.

For instance, I have the following code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.Main).Include(
                                "~/Scripts/EditorV2/main.js"
                    ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.Main2).Include(
                                "~/Scripts/EditorV2/main2.js"
                    ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.Main3).Include(
                                "~/Scripts/EditorV2/main3.js"
                    ));
```

And what I want is a away to do something like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.AllScripts).Include(
                            BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.Main,
                            BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.Main2,
                            BundlesVirtualPaths.EditorV2.Main3
                ));
```

This can be done? I can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public static class BundleHelpers
{
    public static BundleCollection JoinScriptBundle(this BundleCollection bundleCollection, string virtualPath, params string[] bundlesToJoin)
    {
        var bundleResolver = new BundleResolver(bundleCollection);
        Bundle allScriptBundle = new ScriptBundle(virtualPath);
        foreach (var bundle in bundlesToJoin)
        {
            foreach (var scriptPath in bundleResolver.GetBundleContents(bundle))
            {
                allScriptBundle = allScriptBundle.Include(scriptPath);
            }
        }
        bundleCollection.Add(allScriptBundle);
        return bundleCollection;
    }
}
```

Then you can join your bundles:

```
bundles.JoinScriptBundle("~/bundle/allscript", "~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jqueryval", "~/bundles/modernizr");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it , because you are trying to combine all the `JS` files to a single `bundle` which is right way , but there may not arise the same case every time. so you need to do bundling based on type as follows

**For directories:**

```
 bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/js/vendor").IncludeDirectory(@"~/Scripts/vendors/JQuery", "*.js")
                                                     .IncludeDirectory(@"~/Scripts/vendors/Knockout", "*.js")
                                                     .IncludeDirectory(@"~/Scripts/vendors", "*.js"));
```

**For files:**

```
 bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/js/kendo").Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.core.min.js")
                                        .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.data.min.js")
                                        .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.binder.min.js")
                                        .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.calendar.min.js")
```

**For url :**

```
var CdnPath = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300";
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("mybarbundle", CdnPath).Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question. What I want is, given several virtual paths (each one with several scripts paths asssociated), I want to associated them and all the files to a single new one virtual path so I can save time joining all the scripts paths into a new virtual path